# Удалить ключ и его элементы из массива в случае нахождения пустой строки

Tags: php, массивы

подскажите решение как можно удалить ключ массива ([0]) вместе с его содержанием, если в одном из его элементов содержится "пустая строка", или если в ключе ["text"] обнаруживается ключевое слово "http".

```
    array(45) {
      [0]=>
        ["url"]=>
        ""
        ["text"]=>
  "http://sdsdsd.com"
      }
```

заранее спасибо!

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php

Comment: Это решается всего одной строкой: `$arr = array_map('array_filter', $arr);`

Comment: @Эдуард ну я уже позже вспомнил, а переделывать уже нету возможности)))) Ну а разве оно решиться конкретно при таких то условиях?

Comment: @entithat вот вам __[возможность](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/873086/edit)__ переделать :)  UPD: хотя да, понадобится ещё одна строка для проверки на вхождение `http`

Comment: @Эдуард, можете предложить свой пример? У меня что-то ещё хуже чем этот получается..

Comment: @entithat [пример](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/830cf91bf5e5945221b58947c66f8258a66a3062)

Comment: @Эдуард, отличный пример, но интересно сработает он быстрее первого или нет?))

Comment: @entithat я не производил замеров, т.к. не сторонник экономии на спичках ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$arr = [
    ['url' => '',        'text' => 'http://site.com'], 
    ['url' => 'anytext', 'text' => 'site.com']
];

foreach($arr as $key => $value) {
    foreach($value as $k => $v) {
        if (empty($v) || (preg_match('/http/', $v) && $k == 'text')) {
            unset($arr[$key]);
        }
    }
}
```

Выведет:

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [url] => anytext
            [text] => site.com
        )

)
```